# the Republican id -- meaning?

Tags: comprehension

Example with a context (Vox news story: [The real costs of Donald Trump’s anti-Mexican slur controversy, explained](http://www.vox.com/2015/7/8/8911467/donald-trump-immigrants-boycott)):

## 1:

> Liberal Latino and immigration advocacy groups, on the other hand, are happy to treat Trump as a serious Republican candidate, for the purposes of demanding that other Republicans and the RNC distance themselves from him. They're **treating Trump as the Republican id**: He expresses racist feelings that some liberals suspect many Republicans secretly harbor but lack the cojones to say out loud.

## 2:

> Left-leaning Latino and immigration advocates treat Trump as **the id of white conservatives**, saying things that Ted Cruz, for example, wouldn't say.

How do you exactly understand this type of figure of speech?

Comment: Have you looked it up in a dictionary? Or are you familiar with the theories of Sigmund Freud? This is the standard English translation of Freud's "das Es" in his theory of the structure of the psyche.

Comment: It actually did not occur to me that they were referring to the psychological concept of the 'id' until I saw @StoneyB's comment, and I'm a native speaker that took some psychology courses in college, so I think this is a pretty reasonable question. I can certainly see how the dictionary definition might not be that helpful, as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ID is common as an abbreviation for *identification*, but it will usually be capitialized if meant that way.

*Id* is a term that comes from classic Freudian psychoanalytic theory, where the psyche is explained as having three parts that are in constant conflict with one another, and the *id* is the most primitive or "base" of them.  (The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id,_ego_and_super-ego) article explains it well.)

A child, for example, because his/her personality has not had time to mature, often reacts purely on instinct and desire, and without regard to history or knowledge - he/she could be considered to be mostly driven by *id* without the "refinement" of *ego* or *super-ego*.  Now this could be a good or a bad thing - a good thing if honesty/passion is needed, a bad thing if tact/politeness is needed.

Not necessarily endorsing the meaning of the sentences, but that is how I would interpret the use of *id* in them.